# PHP Script to extract only bundle products from a json file and put them to another file

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am trying to get specific data from a json file. Here is the file:

```
{
    "24-WG085": {
        "sku": "24-WG085",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot",
        "price": 2.25
    },
    "24-WG085-dynamic": {
        "sku": "24-WG085-dynamic",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap Dynamic",
        "price": 10.45
    },
    "24-WG086": {
        "sku": "24-WG086",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap 8 foot",
        "price": 5.3
    },
    "24-WG087": {
        "sku": "24-WG087",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap 10 foot",
        "price": 8.35
    },
    "24-WG085_Group": {
        "sku": "24-WG085_Group",
        "product_type": "bundle",
        "name": "Set of Sprite Yoga Straps",
        "price": 11.4
    },
    "24-WG085-bundle-dynamic": {
        "sku": "24-WG085-bundle-dynamic",
        "product_type": "bundle",
        "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap Dynamic Bundle",
        "price": 14.45
    },
    "24-WG085-bundle-fixed": {
        "sku": "24-WG085-bundle-fixed",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap Fixed Bundle",
        "price": 17.5
    }
}
```

So the idea if the product type is a ,,bundle" to get the key- for example: Sprite Yoga Strap Dynamic Bundle. Here is my code so far:

```
  <?php
  $data = file_get_contents ("php-files-task.json");
    $json = json_decode($data, true);
    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
        } else {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                echo $key . '=>' . $val . '<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');

foreach ($value as $value) {
fputcsv($fp, $value);
}

fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

After I get all bundle products I want to put them in a new file- ,,results.json". I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: `I will appreciate any help.` - with what, i.e. what exactly is the problem that you're facing? What doesn't work? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I am trying to get only the bundle products. Then to put the result in a new json file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the array and build an associative array based on product type then json_encode and save the items you want to keep.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($arr as $key => $item){
    $new[$item['product_type']][$key] = $item;
}

//var_dump($new);

file_put_contents("FilePathAndName.json", json_encode($new['bundle']));
```

Example:
https://3v4l.org/iaKNg

Comment: I replaced my old foreach with yours but now I have these warnings:  
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\new1.php on line 4

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\new1.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: new in C:\xampp\htdocs\new1.php on line 11

Comment: Then you didn't read my code carefully. Look at the link and you will see. Use variable names that tell what they are. In your code you have $json as an array. Why? If it's an array why call it json? Json is a string format. My code uses names that is what they are. $json is json string, $arr is an array.